# Excel function to search a string for a multiple keywords

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have two tables. One of them has server names. The other has timestamps (first table, column `A` below) and text strings (first table, column `B` below). I want to search those strings for a keywords specified in the server table (second table below). If the match is found function writes to the cell name from the header of the column where the keyword is.

Example

[image: Blue table]
[image: Red table]

I want to complete column `System` in Blue table. So for example `C2` should show `GreenSys` and `C8` - `RedSys`.

I have tried using `SEARCH` function but it looks like it tries to match whole table to the string if I pass it as an argument. `VLOOKUP` doesnt work too as I am using two tables. What's the best way for me to get this working?

Comment: Are the name of the servers `ServG#` and `ServR#` where `#` represents a number? Because then, the search would be easier. Also, are the more servers in your actual data?

Comment: There are many different server names and they have different format. Also there are more than two categories (GreenSys and RedSys in example).

Comment: What other format does it have? Because I can propose a formula for your sample, but it mightn't work for your actual data. For instance, you can use `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Serv",B2)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND("ServG",B2)),"RedSys","GreenSys"))` in C2 but this works only for the sample.

Comment: I dont think that will work as there are around 200 servers. Thats why i want to use the second table as reference as to not write every single keyword to the formula.

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but when I get excel sheet comparison tasks like this, I've found that using SQL Server is x1,000 easier then trying to get excels searching\querying capabilities to do what I want.  Using a local DB, for each sheet I setup a new table with the columns I need. As for the data itself, if it's not a ton of records I usually just copy\paste, however if it's more than say a few hundred, the SQL import wizard comes in handy.

Comment: @X3074861X Sadly i do not have access to it here. Have to stick to excel or whatever there is in MS Office :/

Answer (score 2):

If you change the way you have the data setup so that it is a bit more Excel-friendly, this can be rather easily accomplished.

The lookup sheet should look like this (the formula below has this as 'Sheet2'):

[image: tigeravatar lookup sheet friendly format]

Then on your main data sheet, in cell C2 and copied down:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2,"*"&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7&"*")),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2,"*"&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7&"*")*ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7))),"")
```

The results look like this:

[image: tigeravatar results of lookup]

Comment: +1 For thinking out of the box :) 
but not sure how easy the rearrangement step is..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this formula to cell`C2`?

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((B2=Sheet2!$A$2:$D$4)*COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1))>0,
INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,SUMPRODUCT((B2=Sheet2!$A$2:$D$4)*COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1)))
,"")
```

I have assumed that the second table is at `Sheet2` and that data is upto column `D`, starting with the headers at `A1`, with the format you describe.

**EDIT:**

I can see you have amended the original post, and my answer no longer meets the specifications. Therefore I think it is best that I delete it.

**EDIT2:**

Added `VBA` solution. Assumptions:

- Orignal data table in Sheet1
- Destination table in Sheet2
- Headers of Sheet1 in 1st row

The below code was tested, it should be OK but needs error handling:

```
Sub moveData()
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim lRowCounter As Long, lColCounter As Long, lValueCounter As Long, lLastRow As Long
    Dim vOriginArray As Variant, vValuesArray As Variant, vDestinationArray As Variant

    ' Database table in Sheet2
    vOriginArray = Sheet2.UsedRange.Value

    ' Destination table in Sheet1
    With Sheet1
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Put the values we need to compare into an array
        vValuesArray = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lLastRow, 2)).Value
        Set rngDestination = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lLastRow, 3))
    End With

    ' We will store the values to an array first and then
    ' back to the sheet, it is faster this way
    ReDim vDestinationArray(1 To rngDestination.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

    ' Loop through all rows and columns, exclude header row
    For lRowCounter = 2 To UBound(vOriginArray, 1)
        For lColCounter = LBound(vOriginArray, 2) To UBound(vOriginArray, 2)
    ' For each entry, find which values match and store them
            For lValueCounter = 1 To UBound(vValuesArray, 1)
                If InStr(1, vValuesArray(lValueCounter, 1), vOriginArray(lRowCounter, lColCounter), vbTextCompare) Then
                    vDestinationArray(lValueCounter, 1) = vOriginArray(1, lColCounter)
                End If
            Next lValueCounter
        Next lColCounter
    Next lRowCounter

    ' Put the data back to excel
    With rngDestination
        .ClearContents
        .Value = vDestinationArray
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the sheet names but the formula writes nothing. Not an error, the cell is just empty.

Comment: that is weird, I just tested it. If you test it with the amended data (ServG2 has started), it will fail..(check my edit)

Comment: I see it now. It also works fine if I only leave server names in there too! But that's not the case with the data I have however. B2 has a lot of text in it and I only want to search by one word. Is it possible to adjust your formula to accommodate that?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible.. I will check it later tonight, and leave this post here for a while (maybe someone figures it out sooner). By the way, this can be done very easily with VBA, in case you are willing to go down this route..

Comment: If it gets me the result I need, sure.

Comment: I added a VBA code that should do what you need - I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that all Servers start with "Serv".. this should work without using vba.

```
=MID(B1,SEARCH("Serv",B1,1),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",B1,SEARCH("Serv",B1,1))),LEN(B1)-SEARCH("Serv",B1,1),SEARCH(" ",B1,SEARCH("Serv",B1,1))-SEARCH("Serv",B1,1)))
```

Essentially the formulas searches for the keyword serv and then attempts to parse until the end of the word to return the full name.

As someone else mentioned, it would be easier to do with vba but then again there is a benefit of not having macros.